# msbuild can't find .NET 'setup.bin' file

Tags: .net-3.5, msbuild, installation

I'm getting the following warning and error from msbuild:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning MSB3155: Item 'Microsoft.Net.Framework.2.0' could not be located in 'C:\src\Oakhurst\trunk\code\VisionCentral'.
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(3604,9): error MSB3147: Could not find required file 'setup.bin' in 'C:\src\Oakhurst\trunk\code\VisionCentral\Engine'.

[This](http://blogs.msdn.com/emmamou/archive/2009/04/08/team-build-for-clickonce-application-with-bootstrapper.aspx) blog post indicates that installing the SDK should fix the problem.  However I've installed the [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en) and it hasn't solved my problem.

What else can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: It looks like your build is expecting .net to be available from source control, rather than as an installation (which is why your install of 3.5 sp1 isn't helping).

Comment: Not really, according to that link, the fact that it was looking for it in the local directory is an artifact of it not knowing where the real path was -- it's a fallback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I just got the publish operation to work, and I did this by using the "Visual Studio 2008 x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt" rather than the "Visual Studio 2008 x64 Win64 Command Prompt".

I really don't know the difference here, and don't have the time to research it, but if someone else knows, that could be useful information to someone.